# AWS IoT - JSON incorrect format

Tags: c, json, freertos, esp32

I am trying to send this JSON packet to AWS IoT, but it is not recognized by AWS. I am using the example ESP32 AWS FreeRTOS code, but cannot understand what would be the correct format for the JSON packet with the following code:

```c
#define echoMAX_DATA_LENGTH 20

char cDataBuffer[ echoMAX_DATA_LENGTH ];

(void) snprintf(cDataBuffer, echoMAX_DATA_LENGTH, "{\"state\":{\"reported\":%.*d}, \"clientToken\":\"%d\"}", x, x, x);

/* Setup the publish parameters. */
memset( &( xPublishParameters ), 0x00, sizeof( xPublishParameters ) );
xPublishParameters.pucTopic = echoTOPIC_NAME;
xPublishParameters.pvData = cDataBuffer;
xPublishParameters.usTopicLength = ( uint16_t ) strlen( ( const char * ) echoTOPIC_NAME );
xPublishParameters.ulDataLength = ( uint32_t ) strlen( cDataBuffer );
xPublishParameters.xQoS = eMQTTQoS1;
```

The AWS test page, cannot display the message and has converted it to UTF-8 (this error message is below)

[image]

Comment: How is cDataBuffer declared? What is the value of echoMAX_DATA_LENGTH?

Comment: char cDataBuffer[ echoMAX_DATA_LENGTH ];

Comment: #define echoMAX_DATA_LENGTH      20   (this could be too short for my message length, it's cutting off the JSON packet)

Comment: Yeah, how would that possibly work if your buffer is too small for the JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Increase `echoMAX_DATA_LENGTH` to be large enough to fit your entire JSON message.

The static part of the JSON in your code (without the values filled in by `snprintf()`) is 34 characters, so there's no way this could ever work with `echoMAX_DATA_LENGTH` set to 20 - it would always produce a fragment of JSON instead of an entire JSON object.

Remember that the length that [snprintf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) uses includes a byte for the C string terminating character '\0', so you'll want to make `echoMAX_DATA_LENGTH` be one greater than the maximum total JSON message length.

When you increase `echoMAX_DATA_LENGTH`, try adding a debug message after the `snprintf()` so that you can see the JSON you're generating. If your code is set up to use `Serial` already, add:

```
Serial.println(cDataBuffer);
```

after the `snprintf()` so you can confirm that you've generated the JSON properly.